# How to find the probability of winning in a tennis game after a certain time?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Two equally strong tennis players, A and B, wager 50 euros and play one set: the player
that wins six games first wins and receives the pot of 100 euro. They agree on no tie-breaks
or ‘two-point difference’ rule. After the seventh game, the score is 4–3 and player A has the
advantage. At that moment a thunderstorm breaks out and the players stop playing.
To what fraction p of the pot is player A entitled?
(a) Argue intuitively why each of the values p = 1, 4/7, 3/5, 7/12 may be reasonable.
Suppose both players agree on playing some (possibly random) number M of extra ‘independent’ games in which either player has a 50% chance to win. Let p = P(A wins the set).
(b) Show mathematically that if M is chosen in the sense that the game stops as soon as
one player wins the set, then p = 11/16.

My question is for a), why can all these probabilities are possible, since I think that can only be one probability, and for b) what is really the number M.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: "Argue intuitively why each of the values p = 1, 4/7, 3/5, 7/12 may be reasonable" : **really**?  The only response that I can think of is that for math students new to the topic, their intuition is not yet developed, so their intuition can not be used to exclude any *candidate-answers*.  This strikes me as a **very** off-the-wall question, and suggests that the question composer is in the wrong line of work.

Comment: I agree with your arguments, but do you have any hint?

Comment: For part (a), the question seems too bizarre.  For part (b), assume that there will be exactly $11$ games played, regardless of whether anyone achieves $6$ wins prior to game 11.  You know that after $11$ games, exactly one of the two players will have won at least $6$ games.  With $7$ games already played, and $4$ games left to play, the player ahead $4$ to $3$ may win $k$ *more* games, where $k$ will be some element in $\{0,1,2,3,4\}.$

Comment: Yes, but M is chosen independently of the initial score (4 to 3) ,why I should care about this?

Comment: "Show mathematically that if M is chosen in the sense that the game stops as soon as one player wins the set, then p = 11/16."  The analysis that I gave in my last comment will hold, even if extra games are not played after the set winner is decided.  My analysis was provided simply for elegance.  Playing the extra games can **never** alter who won the set.  Therefore, if M is chosen so that the set is decided, the analysis in my previous comment stands.